# How to make a Whitehead link in the tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-knots

I made an attempt to make a Hopf link using my own code:

```
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[
    clip width=3,
    flip crossing={2},
    ]
    \strand [ultra thick, red  ] (1.5,0) circle (1.0cm);
    \strand [ultra thick, black] (2.5,0) circle (1.0cm);
\end{knot}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which generates:

[image]

My question is how do we modify my code to get a configuration like this:
[image]

The configuration is used in this [Communications in Mathematical Physics paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00220-019-03671-6) [Commun. Math. Phys. 376, 1073–1154 (2020).](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00220-019-03671-6)

Comment: This feels like you copied a vaguely related example and haven't tried anything on your own but would like us to do the work for you.  Can't you create the loops?  And use `flip crossing` to get the crossings correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in [the comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575912/how-to-make-a-whitehead-link-in-the-tikzpicture#comment1450165_575912) you have to draw the curves and may have to flip some crossing. The `draft mode=crossings` key can be used to see which crossing has which index.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{knot}[%draft mode=crossings, %<- uncomment this to see the crossings
%consider self intersections=true, %<- long compilation time, so two paths
clip width=5,
clip radius=6pt,looseness=1.3]
%
 \strand[thick,blue] (-1,0) to[out=90,in=-90] (1,0); 
 \strand[thick,blue] (1,0) to[out=90,in=-90] (-1,0);
 \strand[thick]  (0,0.6) to[out=0,in=90] (0.5,0)
   to[out=-90,in=0] (0,-0.6) to[out=180,in=-90] 
   (-0.5,0) to[out=90,in=180]cycle;
 \flipcrossings{1,4,5}
\end{knot}
%
\draw[densely dashed,blue,xshift=2mm,-latex] (160:1) arc[start angle=160,end
angle=-160,radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- this is a great smart way to do it!